# For positive numbers a,b,c ,$abc=1$ prove$ \frac{1}{a+b} +\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{c+b} \leq\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

For positive numbers $a$,$b$,$c$ , with $abc=1$ prove $$\frac{1}{a+b} +\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{c+b}  \leq\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Is this a homework question? Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: No,To prove another inequality For $\lambda\geq 1$ ,$\sum\frac{1}{a+b+\lambda} \leq \frac{3}{2+\lambda}$ . I got the above inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated is false.  Take $a=b=0.1$, $c=100$.  $\frac{1}{a+b}=5$.

However, if $\min(a,b,c)\ge 1$ (for example, if they are integers), then it's true, by the other posted solution.